# FragmentPagerAdapter returns a nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to add tabs to the action bar in my android application. Using FragmentPagerAdapter seems a nice idea but when I try to set the adapter to the ViewPager object, it returns a nullpointerexception. Cannot figure out th problem, please help... Here is the partial code segment:

public class Aps_MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
ViewPager vPager;
PackagePagerAdapter pPAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aps__main);
    setTabs();
}

void setTabs() {
    // Creating the adapter that will return a fragment for each sections
    // of the app.
    pPAdapter = new PackagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    try{
        vPager.setAdapter(pPAdapter);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ADAPTER", e.toString());
    }
    vPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < pPAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(pPAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat, please.

Comment: 06-16 22:15:22.943: E/ADAPTER(8539): java.lang.NullPointerException
this what happened...

Comment: is R.id.pager  declared inside activity_aps__main?

Comment: no its declared in a separate xml file named view_pager.xml

Comment: @anas that`s why you get the NPE